# Visualizing and Solving recusrive questions without a computer

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Say I've something like this: (predict the output)

```
void abc (char *s){

    if(s[0]=='\0')
        return;

    abc(s+1);
    abc(s+1);

    printf(“%c “, s[0]);
}
```

It's not tough to solve, but I take too much time doing it and I've to redo such questions 2-3 times because I lose track of the recursion and values of variables(especially when there are 2-3 such recursive statements)

Is there any good method to use when one has to solve such questions?

Comment: Hopefully, you also a verbal description of the algorithm (ideally with pictures and equations). Then you can test it on paper and prove it gives correct solutions. Lastly, it remains to check the code implements the algorithm correctly.

Comment: Have you tried drawing out the calls in a tree?

Answer (score 1):

The basic technique is to first start with a small input. Then try with one larger. Then try with one larger than that. For recursive functions, a pattern should emerge that lets you predict what the next one will look like given you know what the previous one looked like.

So, let's start with an empty string. Easy, nothing is printed.

```
input: ""
output:
```

Next is a string of length one. Almost as easy, the two recursive calls each do nothing (empty string case), and then the string's character is printed.

```
input: "z"
output: z
```

Next is a string of length two. Each of the recursive calls end up printing the second character (string of length one case), and then the first character is printed.

```
input: "yz"
output: zzy
```

So, let's try to predict what will happen for the string of length three case. What will happen is that the substring that excludes the first character gets worked on twice, then the first character is printed. That substring is the string of length two case. So:

```
input: "xyz"
output: zzyzzyx
```

So, it should be clear now how to derive the next output sequence given the current output sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Take a stack of index cards of an appropriate size.  Start tracing the initial call to the recursive function.  When you get another call start a new index card and either put it in front of the first card or behind it (as appropriate).  Sooner or later you will (unless you are tracing an infinite recursion) trace the execution of a call which does not make a recursive call, in which case copy the return value back to the card you came from.

It's probably a good idea to include 'go to card X' and 'came from card Y' on your cards.

In complicated situations you might find it useful to create more than one stack of cards to trace your function calls, oh why the heck, why not call them *call stacks*.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest example for analyzing recursion is [Fibonacci and Factorial function](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~calvin/cs110/RECURSION.html).

This will help you in analyzing recursive functions in a better manner. Whenever you lose track of recursive functions just recall [these](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_recursion.htm) examples.